# Iterate over combinations of items of multiple lists in Python

Tags: python, iteration

I have several lists and I need to do something with each possible combination of these list items. In the case of two lists, I can do:

```
for a in alist:
  for b in blist:
    # do something with a and b
```

However, if there are more lists, say 6 or 7 lists, this method seems reluctant. Is there any way to elegantly implement this iteration?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `itertools.product` to make all possible combinations from your lists. The result will be one long list of `tuple` with an element from each list in the order you passed the list in.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> c = [4,5,6]
>>> import itertools

>>> list(itertools.product(a,b,c))
[(1, 'a', 4), (1, 'a', 5), (1, 'a', 6), (1, 'b', 4), (1, 'b', 5), (1, 'b', 6), (1, 'c', 4), (1, 'c', 5), (1, 'c', 6),
 (2, 'a', 4), (2, 'a', 5), (2, 'a', 6), (2, 'b', 4), (2, 'b', 5), (2, 'b', 6), (2, 'c', 4), (2, 'c', 5), (2, 'c', 6),
(3, 'a', 4), (3, 'a', 5), (3, 'a', 6), (3, 'b', 4), (3, 'b', 5), (3, 'b', 6), (3, 'c', 4), (3, 'c', 5), (3, 'c', 6)]
```

For example

```
for ai, bi, ci in itertools.product(a,b,c):
    print ai, bi, ci
```

Output

```
1 a 4
1 a 5
1 a 6
... etc
```

Comment: Use ```itertools.product(a,b,c)``` as the for statement expression_list without creating new list out of it first.

Answer (score 1):

If there are in fact 6 or 7 lists, it's probably worth going to `itertools.product` for readability. But for simple cases it's straightforward to use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), and it requires no imports. For example:

```
alist = [1, 2, 3]
blist = ['A', 'B', 'C']
clist = ['.', ',', '?']

abc = [(a,b,c) for a in alist for b in blist for c in clist]

for e in abc:
    print("{}{}{} ".format(e[0],e[1],e[2])),

# 1A.  1A,  1A?  1B.  1B,  1B?  1C.  1C,  1C?  2A.  2A,  2A?  2B.  2B,  2B?  2C.  2C,  2C?  3A.  3A,  3A?  3B.  3B,  3B?  3C.  3C,  3C?
```