# Python code keeps getting killed, most likely due to running out of memory, while making a list using iteration

Tags: python-3.x, iteration

I'm trying to solve problem 31 in ProjectEuler.net and the solution I came up with was to make a list of all possible combinations and then only count the ones that add up to £2. To make a list of all possible combinations this is the code I came up with:

```
    c1p = []
for x in range(201):
    c1p.append(x)

c2p = []
for x in range(101):
    c2p.append(x * 2)

c5p = []
for x in range(41):
    c5p.append(x * 5)
c10p = []
for x in range(21):
    c10p.append(x * 10)

c20p = []
for x in range(11):
    c20p.append(x * 20)
c50p = []
for x in range(5):
    c50p.append(x * 50)

c100p = []
for x in range(3):
    c100p.append(x * 100)

counter = 1 #As a single £2 coin is already equal to £2

total_combs = [[a, b, c, d, e, f, g] for a in c1p for b in c2p for c in c5p for d in c10p for e in c20p for f in c50p for g in c100p
```

The way this is currently written, combinations over £2 will keep getting added to the list even though they're not necessary, and stopping this may help it so I don't run out of memory but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Change `[...]` to `(...)` to make it a generator and loop over it to avoid creating a huge list. Alternatively, use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterate over combinations of items of multiple lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24808853/iterate-over-combinations-of-items-of-multiple-lists-in-python)

Comment: None of the solutions fixes it as I run out of memory in both attempts.

Comment: Remove the `list(...)` or the `[...]` A simple loop of `for a, b, c, d, e, f, g in product(c1p, c2p, c5p, c10p, c20p, c50p, c100p)` doesn't consume any memory at all